# How to specialize a templated class at the class level

Tags: c++, templates

Recently I was asked a question. I have the below templated class:

```
template<size_t SIZE>
class Cache
{
    // A lot of class methods omitted

    std::array<int, SIZE> _arr;
};
```

but someone might pass large a size and allocate on the stack, running out of stack memory. So you might suggest changing it to allocate on the heap:

```
template<size_t SIZE>
class Cache
{
    // A lot of class methods omitted

    std::unique_ptr<std::array<int, SIZE>> _arr;
};
```

but now those wanting a small array will pay the cost of indirection (i'm aware this is a very small cost but for the point of the question please accept).

Consequently it was hinted to me template specialization can allow some to choose the small `std::array` implementation and others to allocate their array on the heap.

I presume this specialization must be at the class level, because the `std::array` is a class member.

How is this class template specialization achieved without duplicating all the (omitted) class methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How is this class template specialization achieved without duplicating all the (omitted) class methods?

Abstract the thing you care about away into its own mixin class. For example:

```
template<size_t SIZE, bool> // default case, condition is false
class storage {
    std::unique_ptr<std::array<int, SIZE>> _arr;
protected:
    // constructor too...
    std::array<int, SIZE>& arr() { return *_arr; }
};

template<size_t SIZE> // special case, condition is true
class storage<SIZE, true> {
    std::array<int, SIZE> _arr;
protected:
    // constructor too...
    std::array<int, SIZE>& arr() { return _arr; }
};
```

Then simply have the cache use it as base, while checking SIZE for a threshold:

```
template<size_t SIZE>
class Cache : private storage<SIZE, (SIZE < THRESHOLD)>
{
    // A lot of class methods omitted
    // They now use this->arr();
};
```

You may also opt for composition instead. The specialization is pretty much the same in this case, but `arr()` is gonna need to be public so `Cache` may access it.

Comment: Thanks. Why is there the difference between the number of template parameters/could you declare both with bool? And on the line with `class` why does the second have parameters but the first doesn't?

Comment: @user997112 - The first is the primary template, whereas the second is the specialization. I suppose you could make them both specializations, but you'd still need a primary template declaration.

Comment: Sorry i edited my comment whilst you replied.

Comment: @user997112 - My original comment still kinda answers that. [This is standard specialization syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization).